# How to maintain css transitions in react table on data change

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-table

I'm using [react-table](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-table) (well...) to handle all of my tables in my app.

Basically, I'm trying to think of a way to maintain the CSS transitions in custom cells when the data of the table is changed. I'll give you an example:

I have a table of posts. Each post has an "active" column. This column is a UI switch. When the value of the cell (boolean) is true, the switch is turned on, and when it's off, then it toggles off. Whenever I toggle on or off the switch, there's a small animation that occurs, but not in react-table and I think I know why.

I assume, that whenever the data of the table is changed, then each `Cell` callback is being invoked and it returns a whole new component each time. If I'm wrong (hopefully), what would be the best approach here?

### TL;DR - "Why it's not working"

I have created a demo here - https://codesandbox.io/s/brave-mendeleev-lkf5d?file=/src/index.css

#### This is the expected outcome:

[image: A box with a background transition]

#### This is the actual outcome:

[image: a table with boxes that won't transition]

#### Update

I'm looking for a solution that will update the state while doing the transitioning.

Answer (score 1):

You should make that transition piece into its own element that manages its own state:

```
const TransitionDiv = () => {
  const [active, setActive] = React.useState(false);
  return (
    <div
      className={"switch " + (active ? "active" : "inactive")}
      onClick={() => setActive(!active)}
    />
  );
};
```

Then use it like this:

```
...
          {
            Header: "Switch",
            accessor: "isActive",
            Cell: ({ value, cell: { row } }) => <TransitionDiv />
          }
...
```

Sandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/admiring-hamilton-ylqtj?file=/src/App.js

Comment: But it's uncontrolled. It doesn't update the actual state... the state of the div should be derived from the props. That's the whole purpose of my goal.

Comment: @EliyaCohen I said *...that manages its own state* not to suggest that *that* was the culprit. I only said it to complete the point; that it should be its own element. This same issue happens inside MUI elements a lot. Encapsulating these transitional components into their elements seems to always fix it.

Comment: I understand, and while I thank you for trying to help, this is not a solution and it completes the transition "point" by breaking the functional one. I can't mark this question as an answer, and I don't mean to sound rude but I would prefer if you could modify your answer so it won't break the functional logic, or delete it. Thanks :)

Comment: @EliyaCohen Fair enough.